# Keil Debugger Variable Watching not working

Tags: arm, keil

I wrote a test code for the Keil debugger. I cannot see in the GPIO port 0 window from pheriperals that the value of the IO0DIR is changed even if my program is running. I created the project for LPC2148 chip from NXP.

NAME AND VERSION: MKD-LITE 4.74

CODE:

```
  #include "lpc214x.h"
    int main()
{
IO0DIR=0xF1241FDA;
}
```

I tried some recommended debugger options for Keil but it still the same.

Does anyone has an idea what could might be ?

Comment: what is the full name and version of your keil ide?

Comment: I edited my question with this information